# Playing around with periodic potentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

So, I was trying to see what introducing a periodic potentials would do to the single particle schrodinger wave equation and here is how I proceed

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+V\psi=E\psi$$
since I know that $V$ is periodic, I write it as 
$$V=\mathop{\sum\sum}_{p,q}C_{p,q}e^{i\vec{k_{p,q}\cdot\vec{r}}}$$
Hence, my equation becomes,
$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(\vec{r})+\mathop{\sum\sum}_{p,q}C_{p,q}\psi(\vec{r})e^{i\vec{k_{p,q}\cdot\vec{r}}}=E\psi(\vec{r})$$
Taking the Fourier transform on both sides
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k}\psi(\vec{k})+\mathop{\sum\sum}_{p,q}C_{p,q}\psi(\vec{k}-\vec{k_{p,q}})=E\psi(\vec{k})$$
$$\mathop{\sum\sum}_{p,q}C_{p,q}\psi(\vec{k}-\vec{k_{p,q}})=(E-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\vec{k}\cdot\vec{k})\psi(\vec{k})$$
Now, my question is that if there is anything that I can say from the last equation? Something about the nature of $\psi(\vec{k})$?
To me it looks like a series in 1D, somewhat of the form $$f(x)=\sum_{k}C_kf(x-kx_0)$$
I am not able to say or deduce anything from that series, is it possible to make some mathematical conclusion about those functions $f(x)$? I would also be happy if I am directed to some literature about them. Please note, I might look really stupid, but I am not a student of mathematics or physics, I am simply an engineer.

Comment: Maybe [Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave#Proof_of_Bloch.27s_theorem) is of interest to you?

Comment: @Demophilus Yes, I was playing around to see where Bloch came up with the idea of two product functions with the same periodicity $u_k(\vec{r})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}$

Comment: @PaulSinclair: How do you note that the LHS is periodic??

Comment: My apologies. The LHS is an expression that is very similar to a summation commonly used with bi-periodic expressions. I saw your reference to periodicity and the general form of the expression and didn't look close enough to note the difference between "very similar to" and "is".